# How to set default values for options page

Tags: customization

here is my option page:

```
class PriceListOptions {
private $price_list_options_options;

public function __construct() {
    add_action( 'admin_menu', array( $this, 'price_list_options_add_plugin_page' ) );
    add_action( 'admin_init', array( $this, 'price_list_options_page_init' ) );
}

public function price_list_options_add_plugin_page() {
    add_theme_page(
        'Price list options', // page_title
        'Price list options', // menu_title
        'manage_options', // capability
        'price-list-options', // menu_slug
        array( $this, 'price_list_options_create_admin_page' ) // function
    );
}

public function price_list_options_create_admin_page() {
    $this->price_list_options_options = get_option( 'price_list_options_option_name' ); ?>

    <div class="wrap">
        <h2>Price list options</h2>
        <p>set price list options</p>
        <?php settings_errors(); ?>

        <form method="post" action="options.php">
            <?php
                settings_fields( 'price_list_options_option_group' );
                do_settings_sections( 'price-list-options-admin' );
                submit_button();
            ?>
        </form>
    </div>
<?php }

public function price_list_options_page_init() {
    register_setting(
        'price_list_options_option_group', // option_group
        'price_list_options_option_name', // option_name
        array( $this, 'price_list_options_sanitize' ) // sanitize_callback
    );

    add_settings_section(
        'price_list_options_setting_section', // id
        'Settings', // title
        array( $this, 'price_list_options_section_info' ), // callback
        'price-list-options-admin' // page
    );

    add_settings_field(
        'price_list_section_title_0', // id
        'Price list section title', // title
        array( $this, 'price_list_section_title_0_callback' ), // callback
        'price-list-options-admin', // page
        'price_list_options_setting_section' // section
    );

    add_settings_field(
        'price_list_section_subtitle_1', // id
        'Price list section subtitle', // title
        array( $this, 'price_list_section_subtitle_1_callback' ), // callback
        'price-list-options-admin', // page
        'price_list_options_setting_section' // section
    );

    add_settings_field(
        'price_list_section_subtitle_2', // id
        'Price list section subtitle', // title
        array( $this, 'price_list_section_subtitle_2_callback' ), // callback
        'price-list-options-admin', // page
        'price_list_options_setting_section' // section
    );

    add_settings_field(
        'price_plan_1_title_3', // id
        'Price plan 1 title', // title
        array( $this, 'price_plan_1_title_3_callback' ), // callback
        'price-list-options-admin', // page
        'price_list_options_setting_section' // section
    );

    add_settings_field(
        'price_currency_4', // id
        'Price currency', // title
        array( $this, 'price_currency_4_callback' ), // callback
        'price-list-options-admin', // page
        'price_list_options_setting_section' // section
    );

    add_settings_field(
        'price_plan_1_price_5', // id
        'Price plan 1 price', // title
        array( $this, 'price_plan_1_price_5_callback' ), // callback
        'price-list-options-admin', // page
        'price_list_options_setting_section' // section
    );

    add_settings_field(
        'price_plan_1_period_6', // id
        'Price plan 1 period', // title
        array( $this, 'price_plan_1_period_6_callback' ), // callback
        'price-list-options-admin', // page
        'price_list_options_setting_section' // section
    );

    add_settings_field(
        'price_plan_1_info_7', // id
        'Price plan 1 info', // title
        array( $this, 'price_plan_1_info_7_callback' ), // callback
        'price-list-options-admin', // page
        'price_list_options_setting_section' // section
    );

    add_settings_field(
        'price_plan_1_features_8', // id
        'Price plan 1 features', // title
        array( $this, 'price_plan_1_features_8_callback' ), // callback
        'price-list-options-admin', // page
        'price_list_options_setting_section' // section
    );

    add_settings_field(
        'price_plan_1_button_title_9', // id
        'Price plan 1 button title', // title
        array( $this, 'price_plan_1_button_title_9_callback' ), // callback
        'price-list-options-admin', // page
        'price_list_options_setting_section' // section
    );

    add_settings_field(
        'price_plan_1_button_url_10', // id
        'Price plan 1 button URL', // title
        array( $this, 'price_plan_1_button_url_10_callback' ), // callback
        'price-list-options-admin', // page
        'price_list_options_setting_section' // section
    );

    add_settings_field(
        'price_plan_1_panel_color_11', // id
        'Price plan 1 panel color', // title
        array( $this, 'price_plan_1_panel_color_11_callback' ), // callback
        'price-list-options-admin', // page
        'price_list_options_setting_section' // section
    );
}

public function price_list_options_sanitize($input) {
    $sanitary_values = array();
    $defaults = array (
'price_list_section_title_0' => 'test',
'do_extra_thing' => false
    );

    if ( isset( $input['price_list_section_title_0'] ) ) {
        $sanitary_values['price_list_section_title_0'] = wp_parse_args(sanitize_text_field( $input['price_list_section_title_0'], $defaults ));
    }



    if ( isset( $input['price_list_section_subtitle_1'] ) ) {
        $sanitary_values['price_list_section_subtitle_1'] = sanitize_text_field( $input['price_list_section_subtitle_1'] );
    }

    if ( isset( $input['price_list_section_subtitle_2'] ) ) {
        $sanitary_values['price_list_section_subtitle_2'] = sanitize_text_field( $input['price_list_section_subtitle_2'] );
    }

    if ( isset( $input['price_plan_1_title_3'] ) ) {
        $sanitary_values['price_plan_1_title_3'] = sanitize_text_field( $input['price_plan_1_title_3'] );
    }

    if ( isset( $input['price_currency_4'] ) ) {
        $sanitary_values['price_currency_4'] = sanitize_text_field( $input['price_currency_4'] );
    }

    if ( isset( $input['price_plan_1_price_5'] ) ) {
        $sanitary_values['price_plan_1_price_5'] = sanitize_text_field( $input['price_plan_1_price_5'] );
    }

    if ( isset( $input['price_plan_1_period_6'] ) ) {
        $sanitary_values['price_plan_1_period_6'] = sanitize_text_field( $input['price_plan_1_period_6'] );
    }

    if ( isset( $input['price_plan_1_info_7'] ) ) {
        $sanitary_values['price_plan_1_info_7'] = sanitize_text_field( $input['price_plan_1_info_7'] );
    }

    if ( isset( $input['price_plan_1_features_8'] ) ) {
        $sanitary_values['price_plan_1_features_8'] = esc_textarea( $input['price_plan_1_features_8'] );
    }

    if ( isset( $input['price_plan_1_button_title_9'] ) ) {
        $sanitary_values['price_plan_1_button_title_9'] = sanitize_text_field( $input['price_plan_1_button_title_9'] );
    }

    if ( isset( $input['price_plan_1_button_url_10'] ) ) {
        $sanitary_values['price_plan_1_button_url_10'] = sanitize_text_field( $input['price_plan_1_button_url_10'] );
    }

    if ( isset( $input['price_plan_1_panel_color_11'] ) ) {
        $sanitary_values['price_plan_1_panel_color_11'] = sanitize_text_field( $input['price_plan_1_panel_color_11'] );
    }

    return $sanitary_values;
}

public function price_list_options_section_info() {

}

public function price_list_section_title_0_callback() {
    printf(
        '<input class="regular-text" type="text" name="price_list_options_option_name[price_list_section_title_0]" id="price_list_section_title_0" value="%s">',
        isset( $this->price_list_options_options['price_list_section_title_0'] ) ? esc_attr( $this->price_list_options_options['price_list_section_title_0']) : ''
    );
}

public function price_list_section_subtitle_1_callback() {
    printf(
        '<input class="regular-text" type="text" name="price_list_options_option_name[price_list_section_subtitle_1]" id="price_list_section_subtitle_1" value="%s">',
        isset( $this->price_list_options_options['price_list_section_subtitle_1'] ) ? esc_attr( $this->price_list_options_options['price_list_section_subtitle_1']) : ''
    );
}

public function price_list_section_subtitle_2_callback() {
    printf(
        '<input class="regular-text" type="text" name="price_list_options_option_name[price_list_section_subtitle_2]" id="price_list_section_subtitle_2" value="%s">',
        isset( $this->price_list_options_options['price_list_section_subtitle_2'] ) ? esc_attr( $this->price_list_options_options['price_list_section_subtitle_2']) : ''
    );
}

public function price_plan_1_title_3_callback() {
    printf(
        '<input class="regular-text" type="text" name="price_list_options_option_name[price_plan_1_title_3]" id="price_plan_1_title_3" value="%s">',
        isset( $this->price_list_options_options['price_plan_1_title_3'] ) ? esc_attr( $this->price_list_options_options['price_plan_1_title_3']) : ''
    );
}

public function price_currency_4_callback() {
    printf(
        '<input class="regular-text" type="text" name="price_list_options_option_name[price_currency_4]" id="price_currency_4" value="%s">',
        isset( $this->price_list_options_options['price_currency_4'] ) ? esc_attr( $this->price_list_options_options['price_currency_4']) : ''
    );
}

public function price_plan_1_price_5_callback() {
    printf(
        '<input class="regular-text" type="text" name="price_list_options_option_name[price_plan_1_price_5]" id="price_plan_1_price_5" value="%s">',
        isset( $this->price_list_options_options['price_plan_1_price_5'] ) ? esc_attr( $this->price_list_options_options['price_plan_1_price_5']) : ''
    );
}

public function price_plan_1_period_6_callback() {
    printf(
        '<input class="regular-text" type="text" name="price_list_options_option_name[price_plan_1_period_6]" id="price_plan_1_period_6" value="%s">',
        isset( $this->price_list_options_options['price_plan_1_period_6'] ) ? esc_attr( $this->price_list_options_options['price_plan_1_period_6']) : ''
    );
}

public function price_plan_1_info_7_callback() {
    printf(
        '<input class="regular-text" type="text" name="price_list_options_option_name[price_plan_1_info_7]" id="price_plan_1_info_7" value="%s">',
        isset( $this->price_list_options_options['price_plan_1_info_7'] ) ? esc_attr( $this->price_list_options_options['price_plan_1_info_7']) : ''
    );
}

public function price_plan_1_features_8_callback() {
    printf(
        '<textarea class="large-text" rows="5" name="price_list_options_option_name[price_plan_1_features_8]" id="price_plan_1_features_8">%s</textarea>',
        isset( $this->price_list_options_options['price_plan_1_features_8'] ) ? esc_attr( $this->price_list_options_options['price_plan_1_features_8']) : ''
    );
}

public function price_plan_1_button_title_9_callback() {
    printf(
        '<input class="regular-text" type="text" name="price_list_options_option_name[price_plan_1_button_title_9]" id="price_plan_1_button_title_9" value="%s">',
        isset( $this->price_list_options_options['price_plan_1_button_title_9'] ) ? esc_attr( $this->price_list_options_options['price_plan_1_button_title_9']) : ''
    );
}

public function price_plan_1_button_url_10_callback() {
    printf(
        '<input class="regular-text" type="text" name="price_list_options_option_name[price_plan_1_button_url_10]" id="price_plan_1_button_url_10" value="%s">',
        isset( $this->price_list_options_options['price_plan_1_button_url_10'] ) ? esc_attr( $this->price_list_options_options['price_plan_1_button_url_10']) : ''
    );
}

public function price_plan_1_panel_color_11_callback() {
    printf(
        '<input class="regular-text" type="text" name="price_list_options_option_name[price_plan_1_panel_color_11]" id="price_plan_1_panel_color_11" value="%s">',
        isset( $this->price_list_options_options['price_plan_1_panel_color_11'] ) ? esc_attr( $this->price_list_options_options['price_plan_1_panel_color_11']) : ''
    );
}

}



// Parse incomming $args into an array and merge it with $defaults

if ( is_admin() )
    $price_list_options = new PriceListOptions();

/* 
 * Retrieve this value with:
 * $price_list_options_options = get_option( 'price_list_options_option_name' ); // Array of All Options
 * $price_list_section_title_0 = $price_list_options_options['price_list_section_title_0']; // Price list section title
 * $price_list_section_subtitle_1 = $price_list_options_options['price_list_section_subtitle_1']; // Price list section subtitle
 * $price_list_section_subtitle_2 = $price_list_options_options['price_list_section_subtitle_2']; // Price list section subtitle
 * $price_plan_1_title_3 = $price_list_options_options['price_plan_1_title_3']; // Price plan 1 title
 * $price_currency_4 = $price_list_options_options['price_currency_4']; // Price currency
 * $price_plan_1_price_5 = $price_list_options_options['price_plan_1_price_5']; // Price plan 1 price
 * $price_plan_1_period_6 = $price_list_options_options['price_plan_1_period_6']; // Price plan 1 period
 * $price_plan_1_info_7 = $price_list_options_options['price_plan_1_info_7']; // Price plan 1 info
 * $price_plan_1_features_8 = $price_list_options_options['price_plan_1_features_8']; // Price plan 1 features
 * $price_plan_1_button_title_9 = $price_list_options_options['price_plan_1_button_title_9']; // Price plan 1 button title
 * $price_plan_1_button_url_10 = $price_list_options_options['price_plan_1_button_url_10']; // Price plan 1 button URL
 * $price_plan_1_panel_color_11 = $price_list_options_options['price_plan_1_panel_color_11']; // Price plan 1 panel color
 */
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your option page. Do you have a question?

Comment: Also, consider re-factoring that code for reuse.  You have a lot of repetition and could probably be reduced down to a couple of functions using PHP loop structures.  The way it is presented now, it is going to be very difficult to maintain.

Answer (score -1):

This can be done by storing a version for your plugin and check if that version exists, it means the plugin is installed and if it does not exist then you can setup default options "once only".

#### Check if plugin is installed, if it is not then setup default options and store a plugin version to avoid resetting your options on every page load

```
// check for new installation and setup default options
add_action( 'init', 'check_plugin_version' );
function check_plugin_version() {

    // this will run your default option setup if the version does not exist
    if ( ! defined( 'IFRAME_REQUEST' ) && get_option( 'my_plugin_version' ) == null ) {
        setup_options();
        update_option( 'my_plugin_version', '1.0.0' );
    }
}
```

#### Setup default options

```
// setup default options
function setup_options() {

    // here you can save your default options
    // the first time your plugin will run

    update_option( 'myoption_id1', '...' );
    update_option( 'myoption_id2', '...' );
    //etc

}
```

Answer (score -1):

The best is to set your default value on the activation hook and add a fallback if the user delete this value on the options page.

```
register_activation_hook(   __FILE__, array($this, '_plugin_activation') );

public function _plugin_activation(){
    if(!get_option('price_list_options_option_name')) {
    //not present, so add new options
    $options = array(
        'price_list_section_title_0'=> 'default title',
        'price_list_section_subtitle_1'=> 'default subtitle',
        etc...

    );

    add_option('price_list_options_option_name', $options);
  }
}
```

You can use the same array of options (and default values) for both sanitize custom functions and _plugin_activation options array to get the same default values in a easy way. i.e: in your __construct(), add,  $this->array_of_default_value = array('price_list_section_title_0'=> 'default title', 'price_list_section_subtitle_1'=> 'default subtitle', etc...);

When you save option value from options page, check $_POST name.

```
if(isset($_POST['price_list_section_title_0')== ''){
    $default_value = $this->array_of_default_value['price_list_section_title_0'];
    update_option('price_list_options_option_name', 'price_list_section_title_0', $default_value);
}
```